# How to mark artifacts as "validated by QA"?

Tags: azure-devops

**Context**

We have a C# project, hosted in Azure devops.

We have a pretty standard workflow :

1. build + unit tests,
2. manual QA,
3. then mark the built artifacts as "validated by QA".

These artifacts are then made available to our deployment team.

Since our product is deployed on our clients' premises, the actual deployment will not be triggered from the azure pipeline.

**Situation**

So far, we work with a build job, and we communicate with the deployment team by sending a notification : "build 345 is validated, use that one for deployment".

The problem is : they basically have access to the list of *all* builds, including the  ones which were built correctly, but where QA found a bug for example.

**What I would like to have**

Give the deployment team access to a section where only validated builds are published.

This could be :

- using a release pipeline : let the result of the release pipeline be to offer the artifacts for download
  but I did't find an action which just states "publish the artifacts"
- in the build pipeline, keep the builds in a "not yet completed" state, and wait for a manual action of the QA team to flag them as "success" or "failure".
  I don't see a way to add a manual step to a "Build" job (and I think this would be a bad setup for a build job anyway)

**Question**

What would be the prefered way to represent this workflow in azure devops ?

Answer (score 0):

Then you could have a release pipeline with only these tasks:

**1. Manual intervention** Sends an e-mail to the QA-team telling them to do their thing with build x.y.z. When the build is approved for release, someone from the QA-team signs into Azure Devops and lets the release resume.

**2. Notification** E-mail or whatever notification you're using goes out to the deployment team, informing them about the newly approved build.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hadn't stated my need explicitly enough. Please check my edits.